# Android the difference between onHandleIntent & onStartCommand

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I am currently writing a android program which needs an `IntentService`. When I put the code in the `onHandleIntent` function, the code does not run, but it doesn't give errors in the `MainActivity`. But when I copy my code into the `onStartCommand`, it runs perfectly.

The problem is that I wanna know what are the differences between `onHandleIntent` and `onStartCommand`. Thanks.

CODE:

In `onHandleIntent`:

```
System.out.println("SERVICE STARTED! ! !");
//System.out.println(intent.getBooleanExtra("once", Boolean.FALSE));
if (intent.getBooleanExtra("once", Boolean.FALSE)) {
    Check();
}
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As from [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService):

The `IntentService` does the following:

> - Creates a default worker thread that executes all intents delivered to `onStartCommand()` separate from your application's main thread.
> - Creates a work queue that passes one intent at a time to your `onHandleIntent()` implementation, so you never have to worry about
>     multi-threading.
> - Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call `stopSelf()`.
> - Provides default implementation of `onBind()` that returns `null`.
> - **Provides a default implementation of `onStartCommand()` that sends the intent to the work queue and then to your `onHandleIntent()`
>     implementation.**

And also:

> All this adds up to the fact that all you need to do is implement
>   `onHandleIntent()` to do the work provided by the client. (Though, you
>   also need to provide a small constructor for the service.)

So an `IntentService` is a "Custom" `Service` with those special properties. So there's no need to override the `onStartCommand()`, actually, **you shouldn't do it** unless you're using the regular `Service` class.

Some example of `IntentService` usage:

**Activity.java**

```
Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourIntentService.class);
it.putExtra("Key", "Value");
startService(it);
```

**YourIntentService.java**

```
public YourIntentService() {
    super("YourIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        // Do whatever you need to do here.
    }
    //...
}
```

You can also check [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) or [this one](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android#4-create-an-intentservice) for more info about `Service` and `IntentService`.

Also, check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Comment: Wow, this was incredibly thorough. Nice answer!

Comment: I have gone through the tutorials, they are great! But is the problem that I haven't `@overide` the `onStartCommand` or the `onHandleIntent`?

Comment: You told on the question that you did override the `onStartCommand`, and you shouldn't do that on `IntentService`. Use `onHandleIntent` instead, it's automatically called.

Comment: no, I didn't override both of them. So the solution is that I put my code in the `onHandleIntent()` function, override it, and just leave `return Service.START_STICKY;` in the `onStartCommand()` function and not override it. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually if you're using IntentService you shouldn't even bother to write a onStartCommand method at all. Put your logic inside the onHandleIntent instead.

Answer (score 5):

`onStartCommand()` is used when you use a `Service`. `onHandleIntent()` should be used instead when you use an `IntentService`. `IntentService` extends `Service`. And as per documentation

> "You should not override this method(`onStartCommand`) for your
>   IntentService. Instead, override `onHandleIntent(Intent)`, which the
>   system calls when the IntentService receives a start request."

If you have overridden `onStartCommand()`, that might be why your `onHandleIntent()` is not getting called.

Comment: If you **do** override `onStartCommand()` when using `IntentService` you won't get your `onHandleIntent()` called later on, **unless** the last line of your `onStartCommand()` is `return super.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not override `onStartCommand()` for your `IntentService`.

If you do, make sure to `return super.onStartCommand();` because that sends the `Intent` to the work queue and then to your `onHandleIntent()` implementation.